# How to extract content from website(url) using machine learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I have used `scrapy` (beautiful soup module) to extract specific content from website (given URL).
But I want to do the same in machine learning `Python`.

Is there any way?

I searched a lot but found none. Everyone in internet uses `scrapy`.
But I want to extract content from website using `Python` machine learning.

`Beautifulsoup`, which I tried, follows:

```py
url='https://bevco.in/sales-details/'
response=requests.get(url=url).content
# print(response)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response,'lxml')
table=soup.table#returns 1st table tag. to extract inbetween table use find medthod
# print(table)
thead=table.find("thead").find_all('td')
# print(thead[0].text)
headings=[td.text for td in thead]
# print(headings)
sheet.append(headings)
    
rows=table.find("tfoot").find_all("tr")
for i in rows:
    row_data=[td.text.strip() for td in i.find_all('td')]#strip remove tab newline etc
    sheet.append(row_data)
excel.save("SalesDetails1.xlsx")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Question needs improvment and some more details to clarify the issue and focus - May take a minute or two to take the [tour] and read [ask]. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, but starting with the point of extracting / scrape information from table, I would recommend using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) to simplify:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html('https://bevco.in/sales-details/')[0]
```

To save the result as excel file:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html('https://bevco.in/sales-details/')[0].to_excel('myfile.xlsx', index=False)
```

Output

|  | Year | IMFLIn Crores(₹) | IMFL(cheap)In Crores(₹) | BEERIn Crores(₹) | FMFLIn Crores(₹) | FMWIn Crores(₹) | TOTAlIn Crores(₹) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2015-2016 | 9221.76 | 913.64 | 1442.24 | nan | nan | 11577.6 |
| 1 | 2016-2017 | 9741.07 | 986.41 | 1415.2 | nan | nan | 12142.7 |
| 2 | 2017-2018 | 11078.1 | 694.46 | 1164.68 | nan | nan | 12937.2 |

...

Comment: Yeah, I have used this code already. What I am asking is how to extract contents(not only tables) from website using machine learning in python.I hope You understood my question. @HedgeHog

Comment: As written, the question is not really understandable, which is why I would recommend [asking a **new** question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and providing it with an exact focus and expected result.